# In a scala project with multiple modules, where to define values accessible globally in all the build.sbt's within the same project

Tags: scala, sbt

In a scala project used as a shared library with multiple modules, where to define values accessible globally in all the build.sbt's within the same project..

project's build.sbt at level 0:

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).settings(commonSettings).aggregate(module1,module2,module3)

lazy val module1 = project.settings(commonSettings)
lazy val module2 = project.settings(commonSettings)
lazy val module3 = project.settings(commonSettings)
```

I need the same version of spark dependency in module1 and module2 but no spark dependency for module3. So I currently have the value sparkVersion in the build.sbt of both module1 and 2 which feels redundant. Also reading the value from a global variable ensures a consistent version is used across all modules.

```
val sparkVersion = "2.1.0"
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
```

Comment: Good Example here! https://github.com/scalafiddle/scalafiddle-core/blob/master/project/Settings.scala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a **Settings.scala** in the root `project/` directory, like:

```
├── build.sbt
├── module1
└── project
    └── Settings.scala
```

`Settings.scala`:

```
object Settings {
  lazy val sparkVersion = "2.1.0"
}
```

in **module1** and **module2** `build.sbt`, you can just use as **Settings.sparkVersion**.